# Exclude file from rewrite htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with excluding specific file from rewrite rule. please check my .htaccess:

```
AuthName "Write a password"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
Require valid-user
index.php

Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

RewriteBase /php-mvc/


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/application/includes/addremove\.php$ [NC]
```

as you can see in last line I put a code which I found on this forum, buAt it's not working - when I'm trying to access this file via browser I receive a 403 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to past

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/application/includes/addremove\.php$ [NC]
```

before

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```